# Creating a dictionary in Python and using it to translate a word

Tags: python

I have created a Spanish-English dictionary in Python and I have stored it using the variable `translation`. I want to use that variable in order to translate a text from Spanish into English. This is the code I have used so far:

```
from corpus.nltk import swadesh
import my_books

es2en = swadesh.entries(['es', 'en'])
translation = dict(es2en)

for sentence in my_books.sents("book_1"):
    for word in my_books.words("book_1"):
        if word in es2en:
            print(translation, end= " ")
        else:
            print("unknown_word", end= " ")
    print("")
```

My problem is that none of the words in `book_1` is actually translated into English, so I get a text full of `unknown word`. I think I'm probably using `translation` in the wrong way... how could I achieve my desired result?

Comment: what does `swadesh.entries` do?

Comment: it's a corpus that includes lists of words in several languages. I'm using it to create a Spanish-English dictionary by "joining" the two appropriate lists

Comment: I think this loop `for word in my_books.words("book_1")` may be wrong. Shouldn't you get words from the `sentence` in the outer loop (otherwise why are you looping over sentences)?

Comment: @slider I have to iterate over words in order to get its corresponding translation. But I'm first iterating over sentences because I want my output to be printed by sentences, and not by word (i.e., not a list of words but rather an actual text)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to translate words in NTLK swadesh corpus regardless of case - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23479912/how-to-translate-words-in-ntlk-swadesh-corpus-regardless-of-case-python)

Comment: @G.Anderson this doesn't have to do with case. All my entries are lowercase

Comment: There are also good examples in that answer for how to do the translation. What do you see if you `print` the first few entries of `my_books.words` and the first few entries of `translation`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.entries()`  method, when given more than one language, returns not a dictionary but a *list of tuples*. See [here](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch02.html#comparative_wordlist_index_term) for an example.

You need to convert your list of pairs (2-tuples) into a dictionary. You are doing that with your `translation =` statement.

However, you then *ignore* the `translation` variable, and check for `if word in es2en:`

You need to check if the word is in `translation`, and subsequently *look up* the correct translation, instead of printing the entire dictionary.

Comment: So `if word in translation: print(translation)` doesn't return my desired output either. What else do I need to modify?

Comment: Have you tried `print(translation[word])`? Remember `translation` is your *dictionary*.  You want to print the translated word from the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a 'Case Sensitivity' issue.
For Example: 
If a dict contain a key 'Bomb' and you will look for 'bomb',
it won't be found.
Lower all the keys at es2en and then look for:`word.lower() in es2en`

Answer (score 0):

i am in progress build a translate machine (language dictionary).

it's in bahasa (indonesia) to english and vice versa.

I build it from zero, what i'm doing is collecting all words in bahasa, and the means of the words.

then compare it with wordnet database (crawl it).

after have a group of meaning and already pairing / grouping the meaning in english with the bahasa, do this, collecting ad many as data, separate it, scienting content and daily content.

tokenize all data in to sentence, make a calculation which word is more high probabilty pairing with other word (both in bahasa and english), this is needed because every words could have several means. this calculation use to choose which word you will use.

example in bahasa:
'bisa', could means poison in bahasa and high probability pair with snake or bite
'bisa', could means can do something in bahasa, high probabilty pairing with verbs words or expression of willing to do something (verbs)

so if the tokenize result pairing with snake or bite,  you search the similar meaning in answer by checking snake and poison in english. and search in english database, and you will found venom always pair with snake(have similar means with toxin / poison).

another group can do by words type (nouns, verbs, adjective, etc).

bisa == poison (noun)

bisa == can (verbs).

that's it. after have the calculation, you don't need the data base, you only need word matching data.
so the calcultaion that you can do by checking online data  (ex: wikipedia) or download it or use bible/book file or any other database that contains lots of sentence.